# $O(n^2)$ running time vs $O(n^2)$ worst case

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics

The use of the phrase "worst-case running time" is really confusing to me.
Isn't plainly stating that the time complexity of an algorithm is $O(n^2)$ supposed to mean that the growth rate of the algorithm is sub-quadratic?
If it is then why do we say that $O(n^2)$ is the worst case time?
Or do they have different meanings?

Thank you.

Comment: Worst-case means simply maximum, while best-case minimum and then we can say to which class of functions the given one belong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that you have an arbitrary array of $n$ numbers, and you give it to  [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) to sort.

The *expected* running time of the algorithm is $O(n \log n)$.  However, if the array is sorted, but in the wrong direction, and you pick the first element as pivot, then the algorithm might actually run in time $O(n^2)$.

That means that if you look at how Quicksort behaves with increasingly larger arrays of reversely sorted data, the time it uses grows as $n^2$.

However, if you spend $O(n)$ time to shuffle the array before sorting it, the *expected* running time is $O(n \log n)$; i.e. very few time will the algorithm spend close to $O(n^2)$ many operations.

---

A different example is with respect to *amortized* complexity.  For example, adding a single element to an ArrayList in Java takes $O(1)$ time, most of the time.  However, on a rare occasion, Java needs to create a new array and copy all the elements over to this new one.  That takes $O(n)$ time.

This means that the *worst case complexity* for ArrayList.add is $O(n)$, but if you do this operation $n$ times, the total complexity is *also* $O(n)$, so we say that the *amortized* complexity is $O(1)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, just one more question. What does it mean for a single input to run in $O(n^2)$? Isn't $O(n^2)$ related to the growth rate of the function and not the individual instances? For example we could say that Quicksort takes $n^2$ operations for some input instances, but I don't understand what is meant by a single instance taking $O(n^2)$. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @kasra You are right, a single instance doesn't have an asymptotic growth, that's why I said that if you look at the list of all reversely sorted lists, then you get $O(n^2)$.  However, it makes it easier to talk about $O$-notation also when discussing single instances, but then it's always assumed that they are part of some infinite distribution.

Comment: Thanks you! Really appreciate it.

Comment: @PålGD When you explain the "the array is sorted in the wrong direction" part, I think it would be better to write $\Omega(n^2)$ or $\Theta(n^2)$ notation instead of $O(n^2)$. Since $O(n^2)$ also means that it could be $O(n)$. Just to be precise :P